# выделение границ строк таблицы

Tags: html, css, frontend

Имеется данный код для таблицы.

```css
#table3 {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #EFEFEF;">
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>hours2</td>
      <td>105 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #EFEFEF;">
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>hours</td>
      <td>100 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #FD9E1E;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Generator</td>
      <td>0 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #FD9E1E;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Burner</td>
      <td>0 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #D92231;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Pump</td>
      <td>1000 hours </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #EFEFEF;">
      <td>abababababab</td>
      <td>hours</td>
      <td>100 hours</td>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 3px solid #EFEFEF;">
      <td>abababababab</td>
      <td>hours2</td>
      <td>200 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

При исполнении можно увидеть, что цветные выделения строк наплывают друг на друга. Как избавиться от этого? Чтобы нужная строка подсвечивалась нужным цветом.

Что пробовал:

1. менял `border-collapse: separate;`
2. устанавливал `border-spacing: 3px 3px`

при данных установках границы пропадают совсем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `box-shadow: inset ...`:

```css
#table3 {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF;">
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>hours2</td>
      <td>105 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF;">
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>hours</td>
      <td>100 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #FD9E1E;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Generator</td>
      <td>0 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #FD9E1E;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Burner</td>
      <td>0 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #D92231;">
      <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>Pump</td>
      <td>1000 hours </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF;">
      <td>abababababab</td>
      <td>hours</td>
      <td>100 hours</td>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF;">
      <td>abababababab</td>
      <td>hours2</td>
      <td>200 hours</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="common-but" value="Null">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```